# Is there any way to read facebook reviews from other user admin?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Is there any way to read facebook reviews from other user admin pages to my website? If it is possible please provide solution?

Comment: [Minimal Comlete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings: *“A Page Access Token is required for all methods.”*

You can only get a page token for pages that you have admin access to.